# Do you strain break material from DME boiled for priming?

Tags: priming-sugar, extract, bottling

When you prime with DME, there is a bit of break material formed when you boil the DME.  How to brew [mentions this](http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter11-3.html), but doesn't say what to do about it or if you should care.  Do you strain this material out?

I recently primed with DME for the first time and did get a wee bit of break material, but I'm not sure a seive would have even caught it.  Is cheese cloth the answer?  Or do you just dump it into your bottling bucket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

I just dump.

---

[Edit, thanks to [TinCoyote](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/users/61/tincoyote)]

When asking these sort of questions I always think about the proportions (or dilution rate).  Pitching a few tens of ml into 19,000 ml won't even register on your tongue.

Comment: Dean's succinct answer is entirely correct. There will be lees in the bottle from natural carbonation anyway.

Comment: Doesn't a cup or so of DME dissolved in two cups of water make for about 700ml, not a few tens?  The values are still very disparate, but not quite so much.

Comment: I thought you were asking about the break material.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about the entire priming solution.  I get it now.